# How i add a javascript file or function to vb.net WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

i want to add a javascript File or Function to vb.net application web browser.
i am using this function:

```
    Dim mScript As HtmlElement
    Dim mHead As HtmlElementCollection
    mHead = Browser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")

    With Browser1
        mScript = .Document.CreateElement("script")
        mScript.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
        mScript.SetAttribute("src", SoftwareROOT & "\plugin.js")

        .Document.Body.AppendChild(mScript)
        .Document.InvokeScript("script_load")
    End With
```

when i execute this function, it creates a new element at the bottom of page successfully.
but the function `.Document.InvokeScript("script_load")` is not working..

**Update:**

JS File is here:

> function script_load(){   alert('Hi from Script'); }
>
> script_load();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for it to load, and that will take at least a little time. Instead, just run the `script_load()` function directly and immediately in your JavaScript; it won't make any difference.

Comment: Browser loads a Page.. when loading is compleate.. it adds a script file.. then try to invoke function.. here is it fails. script file is successfully added.. but didn't invoked.

Comment: @extremerose71: I believe I realize how it works. Put the line `script_load();` at the end of `plugin.js` and it should work. Are you paying attention?

Comment: i already tried this.. js file's code is now at the post.. check it.

Comment: @extremerose71: What's the value of `SOFTWARE_ROOT`? Try using a forward slash (`/plugin.js`) instead, too.

Comment: SOFTWARE_Root is the current directory of Software.. currently it is like "F:\VB2008\new_project".. i recently told you that javascript file is successfully included. i checked this manualy.. but the problem is The function of VB.NET "Browser1.Document.InvokeScript("script_load")" is not working...

Comment: @extremerose71: How have you "checked manually" that it's working? If the script isn't actually running, I'd daresay it's *not* working. So please, listen up - if `script_load();` is at the end of the script, it should work. Apparently the script isn't loading. Try adding `file:///` to the beginning of the `src` attribute, and also try using forward slashes for the entire path.

Comment: it is too easy to check it.. at the end of function i added "textbox3.text = browser1.Document.Body.innerHTML".. and it shows the updated code in textbox.. that's the simple way to check functions is creating a script tag or not... :D

Comment: @extremerose71: Well, just because it's there doesn't mean it's being loaded. So again: try adding `file:///` to the beginning of the string, change the backslashes in the path to forward slashes, and add `script_load()` at the end of the script.

Comment: from your suggestion now the result in manual check is: ""<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="file:///F:/****/*****/software_root/plugin.js"></SCRIPT>"".. i replace folder names by ***** in comments.. but in orignal, it is ok. but still it is not working...

Comment: @extremerose71: Hm... that's really odd. I'm stuck then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub InjectScript(Script As String)
    WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", New Object() {Script})
End Sub
InjectScript(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\Plugin.js".ToString))
```

put your js file in same root